# Django Models and SELECT with joined two or more tables?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I make an select with two (or more) joined tables using Django Models?

For example:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

SELECT * from album, song where (album.id = song.album_id) and (album.artist_id = X)
```

Comment: I was not asking for contents of your database, but your models (or database schema) and sql you would like to perform.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django querysets want to return lists of model instances, which doesn't quite map to the the SQL notion of returning data from multiple tables joined into a single result table.

To achieve the effect of the SQL query you provide as an example, you could do one of the following:

1) If you want to iterate over your data by Songs, you can limit the songs you query by the artist id, like so:

```
songs = Song.objects.filter(album__artist__id=123)
for song in songs:
    print song.name
    print song.album.name
    ... do what ever you need to do with song here ...
```

If you are concerned about performance, you can add  [select_related()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to your queryset.

```
# the depth argument tells django to only follow foreign key relationships
# from Song one level deep
songs = Song.objects.select_related(depth=1).filter(album__artist__id=123)

for song in songs:
    # django has now already fetched the album data, so accessing it
    # from the song instance does not cause an additional database hit
    print song.album.name
```

2) If you want to iterate over your data by Album, you can do things like so:

```
albums = Album.objects.filter(artist__id = 123)
for album in albums:
    for song in album.song_set.all():
        print song.name
        print album.name
        ... etc ...
```

Comment: Does it means that if I want to optimize, it will be better to use example 1 with select_related() ? And all the other cases will be using more than 1 select?

Comment: @ju - I don't see an easy way to pre-fetch related songs through Album.objects in only one query, since select_related() is built to follow foreign_key relationships in only one way. So, yes, I think example 1 with select_related() would probably be the way to go if you want to minimize your database queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform [raw sql query](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), but that's probably not the thing you want to do. Explain how your Models look like and what you want to achieve and probably django ORM will be enough to perform the query.